# Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes in Child Routes

Tags: angular

Here is my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'menu',
  component: MenuComponent,
    children:[
    {
      path: 'config',
      component: ConfigurationComponent
    }]
},
];
```

And here is my menu component html:

```
<app-menu-header></app-menu-header>
<div routerLink="/config">Configuration</div>
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'config'
```

I'm working with Angular 14, the other routes works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parents route in routerLink:

```
<app-menu-header></app-menu-header>
<div routerLink="menu/config">Configuration</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in .../menu try taking out the / in

```
<div routerLink="config">Configuration</div>
```

Or use the full path, "/menu/config"